# Find the length of the longest trailing substring

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to extract the length of the longest substring that ends at the end of the given string and also contains exactly the same character.

For example, given `"aaabbbb"` the required substring would be `"bbbb"` with `length = 4`

While I can think of many ways to do this using `while`/`for` loop, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. Is there any module for this purpose? I do not want to use a `for` loop to find this substring. Is it possible?

Comment: And for `"aabbccccd"`? Only `d`?

Comment: @kaz not really, that describes general ways using slicing etc

Comment: Use re module for regex. That would easily solve this problem.

Comment: @kaz That question really doesn't describe what I want.

Comment: @Shashank I don't have knowledge of how to use regexes, can you provide me the code?

Comment: Well with regex it's simply something like `((.)\2*$)` It's a simple backreference repeat pattern with the end-of-string token. Replace dot with any character class of your desire.

Comment: @xrisk Edited your question to make it better for the future visitors. Nice question there! +1 ...  All the best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>> s = "aaabbbb"
>> len(s) - len(s.rstrip(s[-1]))
4
```

From the docstring of [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

> `S.rstrip([chars])` -> string or unicode
>
> Return a copy of the string S with trailing whitespace removed.
>       If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
>       If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

So this solution takes the length of the original string, and subtracts from it the length of a string where all the identical last characters are stripped off.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted. Python rocks.

Comment: `s[-1]` is the last character of the string `s`. rstrip removes whatever you pass in from the end of the string, removing as many repeated values as exist.

Comment: @jkitchen, and what does rstrip do?

Comment: Updated my edit. I accidentally hit Enter trying to get a multiline comment, but that doesn't work. :)

Comment: Edited your answer to make it better! Great answer. All the best

Comment: @Bhargav Rao Thanks for the edits, I'm still learning the markup language at SO.

Comment: @KennethE.Bellock Cool! All the best! (P.s. Nice photo of you with your dad :P)

Comment: @BhargavRao That's the funniest comment I've read all day. xD

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) module along with [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape)

```
>>> s = "aaabbbb"
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.escape(s[-1]) + '*$'
>>> pat
'b*$'
>>> re.search(pat,s).group()
'bbbb'
```

Other cases

```
>>> s = 'bbbabbbbb'
>>> re.search(pat,s).group()
'bbbbb'
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> re.search(pat,s).group()
'd'
```

You can then use the `len` to find the length.

Comment: This requires me to re-initialize pat everytime I want to do this. I have to do this substring matching a **LOT** of time. Is creating the regex not possible with referencing the actual string?

Comment: I would use `re.escape(s[-1]) + '*$'` since that will work properly for metacharacters like `]` or `^`

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination Wait! Does that mean the brackets around `s[-1]` is redundant?

Comment: right, don't put it in a character class, `re.escape()` produces a regex that matches its argument exactly!  all that's left is to ask for repeats at the end of the input, ie `+ '*$'`

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination Oh Okay. Understood. I will edit the answer along with the changes in the REPL.. Thanks again

Comment: @xrisk Regexes take a lot of time itself! So you would be better off using a non regex solution

Comment: @BhargavRao still thanks for providing an alternate solution :)